# Set a method which is defined in child to a Parent class reference or add it to a parent object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, casting

My requirement is to append `service` to the existing `Name`, so I have written the logic as above.

Currently I am passing `ServiceIn` to the existing constructor as shown above in the class `ServiceImpl`, but they don't want me to add it as an additional argument.

So any idea of how can I add my `Servi` to the existing `serviceInstanceType`?

Here the problem comes from the fact that the service is a method of `service`(the parent) object so it is directly being accessed through getters and setters.

But whereas, `get` and `setid` are in `ServiceIn`(child class), I am casting it and getting the value and passing it later on.

Any suggestions how can I pass the `tsServiceInstance.setSiServiceId` to the `ServiceIn` class respecting the above?

Comment: Why don't you add as setter?

Comment: We cannot add a setter parent class is coming from an api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple:

In java there is the notion of extending classes. So instead of calling the parent class directly, create another class that extends the parent class (which is coming from an `api`) and add all the missing methods to it.

Comment: @nagmafirdose I hope it answers your question

Comment: And we can also do it in another  way that, As we are already extending the parent class , i down casted it and now we can access all methods from child class object reference and i have setted the values using child class oject reference . This worked for me.